# Link error trying to compile XLA AOT for Tensorflow

Tags: python, bazel, tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/tfcompile) to build an XLA AOT example (with things taken from [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13482#issuecomment-335702425)). I've been able to build Tensorflow from source and get XLA JIT working on the small [mnist_softmax_xla.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax_xla.py).

The steps I've done so far are:

**1)**

```
#from tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests
python3 ./make_test_graphs.py --out_dir=./
```

**2)** I also had to change line 21 of `/home/m2angus/tensorflow/third_party/llvm/llvm.BUILD` to:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
```

This was to prevent errors with bazel.

**3)**

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda --verbose_failures --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" //tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:my_binary
```

With the following files:

**`tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/my_code.cc`**

```
#define EIGEN_USE_THREADS
#define EIGEN_USE_CUSTOM_THREAD_POOL

#include <iostream>
#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
#include "tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/test_graph_tfmatmul.h" // generated

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Eigen::ThreadPool tp(2);  // Size the thread pool as appropriate.
    Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice device(&tp, tp.NumThreads());

    foo::bar::MatMulComp matmul;
    matmul.set_thread_pool(&device);

    // Set up args and run the computation.
    const float args[12] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    std::copy(args + 0, args + 6, matmul.arg0_data());
    std::copy(args + 6, args + 12, matmul.arg1_data());
    matmul.Run();

    // Check result
    if (matmul.result0(0, 0) == 58) {
        std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed. Expected value 58 at 0,0. Got:"
                    << matmul.result0(0, 0) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**`tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/BUILD`**

```
# Example of linking your binary
# Also see //third_party/tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/BUILD
load("//tensorflow/compiler/aot:tfcompile.bzl", "tf_library")

# The same tf_library call from step 2 above.
tf_library(
    name = "test_graph_tfmatmul",
    cpp_class = "foo::bar::MatMulComp",
    graph = "test_graph_tfmatmul.pb",
    config = "test_graph_tfmatmul.config.pbtxt",
)

# The executable code generated by tf_library can then be linked into your code.
cc_binary(
    name = "my_binary",
    srcs = [
        "my_code.cc",  # include test_graph_tfmatmul.h to access the generated header
    ],
    deps = [
        ":test_graph_tfmatmul",  # link in the generated object file
        "//tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla:common",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla:tf2xla_proto",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla:tf2xla_util",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla:xla_compiler",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels:xla_cpu_only_ops",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels:xla_ops",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/xla:shape_util",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/xla:statusor",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/xla:util",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/xla:xla_data_proto",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/xla/client:client_library",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/xla/client:compile_only_client",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/xla/service:compiler",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu:cpu_compiler",
        "//tensorflow/core:core_cpu",
        "//tensorflow/core:core_cpu_internal",
        "//tensorflow/core:framework",
        "//tensorflow/core:framework_internal",
        "//tensorflow/core:lib",
        "//tensorflow/core:protos_all_cc",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla:xla_compiled_cpu_function",
        "//third_party/eigen3",
    ],
    linkopts = [
        "-lpthread",
    ]
)
```

The error output is huge so I'll just put a snippet of it

```
Loading: 
Loading: 0 packages loaded
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:my_binary (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[0 / 2] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
[1 / 2] Linking tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/my_binary; 1s local
ERROR: /home/m2angus/tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/BUILD:14:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:my_binary' failed (Exit 1): crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/m2angus/.cache/bazel/_bazel_m2angus/5e7d70ea4881ca91d8032ed9fd943ff8/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=/usr/local/cuda \
    CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 \
    GCC_HOST_COMPILER_PATH=/usr/bin/gcc \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python3 \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages \
    TF_CUDA_CLANG=0 \
    TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=6.1 \
    TF_CUDA_VERSION=8.0 \
    TF_CUDNN_VERSION=6 \
    TF_NEED_CUDA=1 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL=0 \
  external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -o bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/my_binary '-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../../../../_solib_local/_U@local_Uconfig_Ucuda_S_Scuda_Ccudart___Uexternal_Slocal_Uconfig_Ucuda_Scuda_Scuda_Slib' -Lbazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U@local_Uconfig_Ucuda_S_Scuda_Ccudart___Uexternal_Slocal_Uconfig_Ucuda_Scuda_Scuda_Slib -pthread -Wl,-rpath,../local_config_cuda/cuda/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,../local_config_cuda/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 -Wl,-no-as-needed -B/usr/bin/ -pie -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -no-canonical-prefixes -pass-exit-codes '-Wl,--build-id=md5' '-Wl,--hash-style=gnu' -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,@bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/my_binary-2.params)
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libgather_op_kernel_float_int32.lo(gather_op_kernel_float_int32.o): In function `gather_float_int32_xla_impl':
gather_op_kernel_float_int32.cc:(.text.gather_float_int32_xla_impl+0x0): multiple definition of `gather_float_int32_xla_impl'
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libgather_op_kernel_float_int32.lo(gather_op_kernel_float_int32.o):gather_op_kernel_float_int32.cc:(.text.gather_float_int32_xla_impl+0x0): first defined here
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libgather_op_kernel_float_int64.lo(gather_op_kernel_float_int64.o): In function `gather_float_int64_xla_impl':
gather_op_kernel_float_int64.cc:(.text.gather_float_int64_xla_impl+0x0): multiple definition of `gather_float_int64_xla_impl'
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libgather_op_kernel_float_int64.lo(gather_op_kernel_float_int64.o):gather_op_kernel_float_int64.cc:(.text.gather_float_int64_xla_impl+0x0): first defined here
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libindex_ops_kernel_argmax_float_1d.lo(index_ops_kernel_argmax_float_1d.o): In function `argmax_float_1d_xla_impl':
index_ops_kernel_argmax_float_1d.cc:(.text.argmax_float_1d_xla_impl+0x0): multiple definition of `argmax_float_1d_xla_impl'
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libindex_ops_kernel_argmax_float_1d.lo(index_ops_kernel_argmax_float_1d.o):index_ops_kernel_argmax_float_1d.cc:(.text.argmax_float_1d_xla_impl+0x0): first defined here
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libindex_ops_kernel_argmax_float_2d.lo(index_ops_kernel_argmax_float_2d.o): In function `argmax_float_2d_xla_impl':
index_ops_kernel_argmax_float_2d.cc:(.text.argmax_float_2d_xla_impl+0x0): multiple definition of `argmax_float_2d_xla_impl'
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libindex_ops_kernel_argmax_float_2d.lo(index_ops_kernel_argmax_float_2d.o):index_ops_kernel_argmax_float_2d.cc:(.text.argmax_float_2d_xla_impl+0x0): first defined here
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libxla_cpu_only_ops.lo(index_ops_cpu.o): In function `tensorflow::(anonymous namespace)::ArgMaxCustomCallOp::~ArgMaxCustomCallOp()':
index_ops_cpu.cc:(.text._ZN10tensorflow12_GLOBAL__N_118ArgMaxCustomCallOpD2Ev+0x10): undefined reference to `tensorflow::OpKernel::~OpKernel()'
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libxla_cpu_only_ops.lo(index_ops_cpu.o): In function `tensorflow::(anonymous namespace)::ArgMaxCustomCallOp::~ArgMaxCustomCallOp()':
index_ops_cpu.cc:(.text._ZN10tensorflow12_GLOBAL__N_118ArgMaxCustomCallOpD0Ev+0x17): undefined reference to `tensorflow::OpKernel::~OpKernel()'
bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libxla_cpu_only_ops.lo(index_ops_cpu.o): In function `tensorflow::Status tensorflow::errors::InvalidArgument<char const*>(char const*)':
index_ops_cpu.cc:(.text._ZN10tensorflow6errors15InvalidArgumentIJPKcEEENS_6StatusEDpT_[_ZN10tensorflow6errors15InvalidArgumentIJPKcEEENS_6StatusEDpT_]+0x34): undefined reference to `tensorflow::strings::StrCat(tensorflow::strings::AlphaNum const&)'
index_ops_cpu.cc:(.text._ZN10tensorflow6errors15InvalidArgumentIJPKcEEENS_6StatusEDpT_[_ZN10tensorflow6errors15InvalidArgumentIJPKcEEENS_6StatusEDpT_]+0x49): undefined reference to `tensorflow::Status::Status(tensorflow::error::Code, tensorflow::StringPiece)'
....
sendrecv_ops.cc:(.text.startup._Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii.constprop.9+0x3a9): undefined reference to `tensorflow::register_op::OpDefBuilderReceiver::OpDefBuilderReceiver(tensorflow::register_op::OpDefBuilderWrapper<true> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Target //tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:my_binary failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 10.513s, Critical Path: 10.10s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

The `....` is pretty much just a bunch of `undefined reference to` errors. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I've also tried moving some of the `deps` from `my_binary` to `test_graph_tfmatmul`, but got the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the link errors I had to use `tf_cc_binary` instead of `cc_binary` in `BUILD` (according to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13267#issuecomment-331681973)). I also had to add the line

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_cc_binary")
```

This is a solution in the context of my post. There are still other errors, but they are outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Just for reference if anyone else runs into the same problems as me. The other errors were because of conflicting dependences. I removed the majority of those and it compiled fine.